# View website as if on a Mac

Tags: macos

The program Multiple IEs allows me to view a website I've created on IE6 (while still having IE 9 on my computer).

Is there a program similar to that which will allow me to view websites on my Windows OS as if I'm running a Mac OS?

Basically, I need to see what websites will look like on a Mac, but all I have is a windows computer.

Comment: If you're serious about testing then you should just buy a low end Mac - second hand Mac Minis are pretty cheap on eBay.

Comment: You can try Safari for windows. It's not a 1:1 port but it's quite close. http://apple.com/safari

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay on Windows you can just use Safari. Except for font differences everything would be practically the same as on Mac.

You can also use Expression Web 4 + Superpreview to get a view of how the site will look (on a Mac)  but it's not very interactive.

Comment: +1 for Safari. There are some trivial differences in font rendering, but under the hood it's the same HTML parsing and layout engine - if an error in your HTML markup is going to make Safari/Mac blow up, it'll make Safari/Windows blow up too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not like the old nightmare of IE5/Mac any more: all major Mac browsers have Windows versions which behave close enough to the Mac version that it usually doesn't matter.

The main remaining differences are:

- different default fonts
- different default font rendering
- different multimedia framework
- potentially different plugin support
- lack of support for automated Windows domain authentication (NTLM, Kerberos)

which are all things you have to cope with for Windows browsers anyway. The differences are probably smaller than the difference between real-IE6 and MultipleIEs-IE6.

If you really need to, it is possible—though against the EULA, and not wholly straightforward—to run OS X on a virtual machine. (eg Virtualbox with an EFI boot CD.) If you need a real, watertight IE6 or 7 environment, you will have to use a virtual machine anyway, as MultipleIEs isn't perfect.

Comment: In in reality there is major differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://browsershots.org/